# Android update listview on focus

Tags: android, listview

Hi I'm trying to use a listview. My listview has a list of items that gets displayed when I first start the program. Then in the same screen if the user pushes a button a new screen pops up and they enter in another item to the list. But after the add item screen closes the list is not updated.

How do you update the list on a refocus? I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding item to the list.